# How to determine size of an tep_db_fetch_array inside a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count, oscommerce

Can't get this.
How to determine size of an tep_db_fetch_array inside a while loop?

I would like to do this:

```
$i=0;
while($a = tep_db_fetch_array($query)){
  if($i==5){
    // start a div i.e.
  }
  //do sth here
  if($i>=count($a)){ 
    //close the div i.e.   
  }
  $i++;       
}
```

but it is not working, because $a is not the whole array, just a pointer to the actual query result. What i am doing wrong, or how to do it?

Comment: out of curiosity: Why don't you just do that after the while loop? The variable $a should then contain the last record.

Comment: because the first initial element is done inside the loop

Comment: Should work nonetheless.

Comment: Yes you are right! I have forgot one important thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the function tep_db_num_rows, like this:

```
$i=0;
while($a = tep_db_fetch_array($query)){
  //do sth here
  if($i>=tep_db_num_rows($query)){ 
    //do sth other here for the last entry   
  }
  $i++;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to FrankZ argument this is the simplest solution:

```
$i=0;
while($a = tep_db_fetch_array($query)){
  if($i==5){
    // start a div i.e.
  }
  //do sth here
  $i++;       
}
if($i>=5){ 
  //close the div i.e.   
}
```

i was so pretty damn